# How Can I find the right network of the transaction? - an emergency question for a newbie

Tags: metamask, wallets, etherscan, faucets

I used '[Goerli faucet](https://goerlifaucet.com/)' and entered my MetaMask wallet address, but now I don't know which network I should use to see how much Ethereum I have because currently, my MetaMask wallet shows that I have nothing.

Is there any way for me to find out which network I should choose on metamask to see my actual balance?
Is there any way for me to see in which network my EtherScan transactions were conducted?

Answer (score 0):

your wallet must have a minimum balance of 0.001 ETH on mainnet to get Goerli testnet tokens. if you have it on the mainnet(Ethereum). then requested for testnet token. you must have it on your wallet, otherwise you won't get that.

So, if you're sure that you followed the above guidance:

Open your metamask and follow these steps:
[image]

then you can see that your balance is increased.
[image]

Pls, vote up if it solved your problem :)